# Div height depending on image in another div

Tags: html, css

I want the left `div` to be in the same height as the right `div` (which contain a image). 
The problem is that the image is fluid (that is, I can't have a specific size on the left `div`).

Is this possible?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <div>text</div>
        <div>text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div>image</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Sadly this cannot be done straight forward with CSS ... It needs JavaScript. Here's how to do it with jQuery

```
var highestCol = Math.max($('.left').height(),$('.right').height());
$('.container > div').height(highestCol);
```

This will get the height of the taller `<div>` then assign it to both the right and left. This way both will have the same height.

I would recommend you add a class like `column` too to your right and left divs. Then you can use :

```
var highestCol = Math.max($('.left').height(),$('.right').height());
$('.column').height(highestCol);
```

And we could use it as a jQuery plugin too ... consider :

```
$.fn.setAllToMaxHeight = function(){
    return this.height( Math.max.apply(this, $.map( this , function(e){
        return $(e).height()
    }) ) );
}
```

This way you can use it on any set of divs you want them to have equal height.

```
$('div.columns').setAllToMaxHeight();
```

And for sure we want our code to run when **all the images** are loaded (because if it's not and the DOM is ready the height wont be correct) so we wrap our code in :

```
$(window).load(function () {
    // use the plugin way :
    $('div.columns').setAllToMaxHeight();

    // or use the other way :
    var highestCol = Math.max($('.left').height(),$('.right').height());
    $('.column').height(highestCol);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

VKen, what it looks like you are trying to achieve is a Faux Column layout.

One very simple (js-less) solution is to use an image that covers the container div:

```
.container{overflow:hidden;background: url(faux_background.jpg) repeat-y}
.left,
.right{float:left;}
.left{width:30%}
```

This does the following: 
The container will wrap around both the left and right divs, regardless of their height.
The left div will always be at 30%.
The background of the container div will give off the illusion of an infinitely growing left div (given the right div is longer, or vice versa).

For more information, A list apart has a nice article on this: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list with different approaches to do this: http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/